# Why does the one-hot-encoding give worse accuracy in this case?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, auto-keras

I have two directories, `train_data_npy` and `valid_data_npy` where there are 3013 and 1506 `*.npy` files, respectively.

Each `*.npy` file has 11 columns of float types, of which the first eight columns are features and the last three columns are one-hot-encoded labels (characters) of three classes.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
f1      f2      f3      f4   f5   f6   f7   f8          ---classes---
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.559   9.22    0.0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
5.512   6.891   10.589  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
7.082   8.71    7.227   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.352   9.883   12.492  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.711   10.422  13.44   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
7.12    9.283   12.723  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.408   9.277   12.542  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.608   9.686   12.793  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
6.723   8.602   12.168  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0         0.0  0.0  1.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

Given the format of the data, I have written two scripts.

`cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_with_ohe.py` uses OHE labels as they are, and `cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_without_ohe.py` converts OHE data into integers.

The first one achieves an accuracy of `0.40`, and the second one achieves an accuracy of `0.97`.

**Why does the one-hot-encoding give worse accuracy in this case?**

---

The Python script's task is to load those `*.npy` files in chunks so that the memory is not overflowed while searching for the best model.

---

```
# File: cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_with_ohe.py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import autokeras as ak
import os

# Update these values to match your actual data
N_FEATURES = 8
N_CLASSES = 3  # Number of classes
BATCH_SIZE = 100

def get_data_generator(folder_path, batch_size, n_features, n_classes):
    """Get a generator returning batches of data from .npy files in the specified folder.
    The shape of the features is (batch_size, n_features).
    The shape of the labels is (batch_size, n_classes).
    """
    def data_generator():
        files = os.listdir(folder_path)
        npy_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.npy')]

        for npy_file in npy_files:
            data = np.load(os.path.join(folder_path, npy_file))
            x = data[:, :n_features]
            y = data[:, n_features:]

            for i in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
                yield x[i:i+batch_size], y[i:i+batch_size]

    return data_generator

train_data_folder = '/home/my_user_name/original_data/train_data_npy'
validation_data_folder = '/home/my_user_name/original_data/valid_data_npy'

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    get_data_generator(train_data_folder, BATCH_SIZE, N_FEATURES, N_CLASSES),
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, N_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, N_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32)  # Labels are now 2D with one-hot encoding
    )
)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    get_data_generator(validation_data_folder, BATCH_SIZE, N_FEATURES, N_CLASSES),
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, N_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, N_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32)  # Labels are now 2D with one-hot encoding
    )
)

# Initialize the structured data classifier.
clf = ak.StructuredDataClassifier(max_trials=10) # Set max_trials to any value you desire.

# Feed the tensorflow Dataset to the classifier.
clf.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100)

# Get the best hyperparameters
best_hps = clf.tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]

# Print the best hyperparameters
print(best_hps)

# Export the best model
model = clf.export_model()

# Save the model in tf format
model.save("heca_v2_model_with_ohe", save_format='tf')  # Note the lack of .h5 extension

# Evaluate the best model with testing data.
print(clf.evaluate(validation_dataset))
```

```
# File: cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_without_ohe.py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import autokeras as ak

N_FEATURES = 8
N_CLASSES = 3  # Number of classes
BATCH_SIZE = 100

def get_data_generator(folder_path, batch_size, n_features):
    """Get a generator returning batches of data from .npy files in the specified folder.

    The shape of the features is (batch_size, n_features).
    """
    def data_generator():
        files = os.listdir(folder_path)
        npy_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.npy')]

        for npy_file in npy_files:
            data = np.load(os.path.join(folder_path, npy_file))
            x = data[:, :n_features]
            y = data[:, n_features:]
            y = np.argmax(y, axis=1)  # Convert one-hot-encoded labels back to integers

            for i in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
                yield x[i:i+batch_size], y[i:i+batch_size]

    return data_generator

train_data_folder = '/home/my_user_name/original_data/train_data_npy'
validation_data_folder = '/home/my_user_name/original_data/valid_data_npy'

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    get_data_generator(train_data_folder, BATCH_SIZE, N_FEATURES),
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, N_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)  # Labels are now 1D integers
    )
)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    get_data_generator(validation_data_folder, BATCH_SIZE, N_FEATURES),
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, N_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)  # Labels are now 1D integers
    )
)

# Initialize the structured data classifier.
clf = ak.StructuredDataClassifier(max_trials=10) # Set max_trials to any value you desire.

# Feed the tensorflow Dataset to the classifier.
clf.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100)

# Get the best hyperparameters
best_hps = clf.tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]

# Print the best hyperparameters
print(best_hps)

# Export the best model
model = clf.export_model()

# Save the model in tf format
model.save("heca_v2_model_without_ohe", save_format='tf')  # Note the lack of .h5 extension

# Evaluate the best model with testing data.
print(clf.evaluate(validation_dataset))
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
    0 MSE C  0.000   0.000  0.000 1 1 1 1  1  0
    1 ASN C  7.042   9.118  0.000 1 1 1 1  1  0
    2 LEU H  5.781   5.488  7.470 0 0 0 0  1  0
    3 THR H  5.399   5.166  6.452 0 0 0 0  0  0
    4 GLU H  5.373   4.852  6.069 0 0 0 0  1  0
    5 LEU H  5.423   5.164  6.197 0 0 0 0  2  0
```

(1) - residue number for debug purpose only (NOT A FEATURE)
(2) - residue type for debug purpose only (NOT A FEATURE)
(3) - secondary structure (TRUE LABEL)
(4) - r13
(5) - r14
(6) - r15
(7) - neighbor count with 4A
(8) - neighbor count with 4.5A
(9) - neighbor count with 5A
(10) - neighbor count with 6A
(11) - neighbor count with 8A
(12) - hydrogen bonds count

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: @stateMachine, this is AutoKeras moder search. I am not specifying any loss function myself.

Comment: Shouldn't you evaluate based on the classes only? Also, there is a parameter for the `StructuredDataClassifier` named `num_classes`. Hmm.

Comment: @doneforaiur, *Shouldn't you evaluate based on the classes only?* --- Why do you say that?

Comment: Is there reason to believe that both reported performance values refer to the classification accuracy.

Comment: @Dave, What else can they be?

Comment: MSE, MAE, RMSE, R^2, MAPE, MASE...

Comment: @Dave, I am not sure.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://autokeras.com/structured_data_classifier/#evaluate), `.evaluate()` "returns the loss, or list of scalars in case of multiple outputs/metrics" etc. So, if you only get one number, this is the loss. It should be two numbers, as the `metrics` parameter in the `StructuredDataClassifier` init defaults to accuracy per the docs. Loss defaults to 'binary_crossentropy' or 'categorical_crossentropy', based on classes. Sometimes a look into the docs could be worth it..

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption 1:**
OHE preprocessing, results in 3 classes, based on the [Structured data classifier documentation](https://autokeras.com/structured_data_classifier/) - `autokeras` will pick `categorical_crossentropy`.

**Assumption 2:**
Without_OHE, it will result in 1 class (with possible integer values 1, 2, or 3). Again, based on the documentation mentioned above - `autokeras` will now pick  `binary_crossentropy` (I guess).

So without the full data (or at least a MVDataset) we have a hard time helping. I would recommend to debug as follows:

- a) Specifiy the loss you want to use in your both scripts explicitly. At least we will know which loss you are using and how the results will look like.
- b) As the second thing you are trying shouts regression problem to me, you should be using the `autokeras'` [Structured data regressor](https://autokeras.com/structured_data_regressor/).

*Note: From my experience (but who am I to judge) I would expect the classification problem to be better performing. As this is an easier task to begin with. So I would not trust your current regression performance, and you did right showing up here.*

Comment: This is a protein data set. Please check the edit.

Comment: Can you try what I propose in my answer under a) and let us know what you found out?

Comment: I appreciate it, thanks. What did solve it for you in the end?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that different random seeds are the reason for your different results.

If you provide the integer class representation to `autokeras`, it will be converted to the one-hot representation automatically. You can check this by running

```
[p.preprocessor for p in clf.outputs[0].in_blocks[0].get_hyper_preprocessors()]
```

at the end of your notebook using the integer class representation which should show the `OneHotEncoder` object at the end of the list. So in both of your notebooks the loss function should be `CategoricalCrossentropy` which you can check by running `clf.outputs[0].in_blocks[0].loss` at the end of your notebooks.

To fix the random seed issue, the `StructuredDataClassifier` constructor provides a `seed` parameter, but in my experience it is not enough (after setting this I still got different results on a toy problem). So do this instead:

```
import keras  # you can do this at the top of your notebook
random_seed = 17  # choose your favorite

keras.utils.set_random_seed(random_seed)
clf = ak.StructuredDataClassifier(overwrite=True, max_trials=10, seed=random_seed)
```

I also added the `overwrite=True` parameter to ensure no previous results are loaded (depending on how you ran your notebooks this could also contribute to the differences).

If I am correct, you might want to increase the `max_trials` parameter later to stabilize the results (that is to see comparable evaluation results for different random seeds). As I see in the `autokeras` code, the default setting is 100.